# Check if one condition includes another

Tags: logic

I have two conditions A and B in a form of "ast tree".
How can I check that B is more strict than A?
I.e. if B is true then A is always true.

Example

A: 
x = 1 and (b = 2 or c = d)

B:
y = 5 and x = 1 and (b = 2 or c = d)

Does B include A -> true

---

A: 
x = 1 and (b = 2 or c = d)

B:
y = 5 and x = 1 and (b = 2 or c = d)

Does B include A -> false

---

This seems to be a common task for a specialist in logical math.
But I have only very basic knowledge about logical arithmetics.
Any articles/studies about subject appreciated.

Comment: An approach might be modelling $A$ and $B$ in a model checker and then verifying if the formula $B \to A$ is tautological. That being said, this is probably way too complex for someone with "only very basic knowledge about logical arithmetics"...

Comment: What form can the conditions take? Without more information, your question can't really be answered: for example, if the only condition that's allowed is "true", then the problem is trivial; if you're allowed conditions such as "If Turing machine $M$ halts on input $x$", then the problem is undecidable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your ASTs have a small number of conditions, then you can use the following naive approach.

1) Convert your ASTs to a CSOP (Canonical Sum Of Products) expression.
     From your example, lets convert each condition to a boolean variable and express $A$ and $B$ as boolean expressions in the following variables

$p: (x ==1)$ 
$q: (y==5)$
$r: (b == 2)$
$s: (c == d)$

Now
$ A: \space p \cdot (r + s)$ 
$B: p \cdot q \cdot (r + s)$
Normalising $A$ and $B$ yields
$A: p \cdot \lnot q \cdot r \cdot \lnot s +
   p \cdot \lnot q \cdot r \cdot s +
   p \cdot q \cdot r \cdot \lnot s +
   p \cdot q \cdot r \cdot s +
   p \cdot \lnot q \cdot \lnot r \cdot s +
   p \cdot q \cdot \lnot r \cdot s
$
$B: p \cdot q \cdot r \cdot \lnot s +
   p \cdot q \cdot \lnot r \cdot s +
   p \cdot q \cdot r \cdot s
$

2) Check if $ B \subseteq A$. In the above example it is true. This implies $B$ is stricter than $A$. If thought logically, all conditions in $B$ are fulfilled by $A$, but $A$ also satisfies other conditions not in $B$.
Hence, $B$ is stricter compared to $A$.

Note: Expanding boolean expressions to normal forms requires exponential space. The algorithm might need some optimisation tweaks for larger expressions.

Comment: Your answer guided me to the right solution - thank you. But I thinking convering to Canonical Product of Sum instead, and after that's done - checking if all terms of one expressions are found in another. Else I don't see a way to "Check if B⊆A" in CSOP.

Comment: @YuriYaryshev Yes. Even CPOS can be used for the task. But use the correct one based on the expression. If an expression has $n$ variables (4 in the example) and the CSOP has $x$ product terms, then CPOS will contain $2^n-x$ sum terms. So choosing the correct Canonical form can reduce the runtime of the algorithm.